# How to run a git command from macOS app in Swift?

Tags: swift, git, macos, shell

I would like to run a git command then launch Xcode from a macOS app.

But I'm currently blocked on the first step: **Running a git command**

I tried a lot of code using `Process`, `NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication` but I'm still blocked. You can see here my last attempt.

```swift
@discardableResult
func shell(_ app: String, _ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/\(app)"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("git", "clone https://github.com/user/repo.git")
```

But an error is thrown:

> git: 'clone https://github.com/user/repo.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Do am I wrong ? Is that a correct way to do ?
Do I need to grant permissions or something like that ?

Comment: Separate arguments: `shell("git", "clone", "https://github.com/user/repo.git")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a single argument to the `git` command: `"clone https://github.com/user/repo.git"`. Instead, you need to pass "clone" and the URL as separate arguments:

```
shell("git", "clone", "https://github.com/user/repo.git")
```